# TinyMCE Custom Styles issue (Having the style just wrap around)

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I created a custom style for the TinyMCE on my wordpress site I am working on. When I highlight a block of text (That includes a H2 and a bullet) and apply the style the H2 tag gets wrapped and the text inside the LI tag gets wrapped. I like have it wrap a div tag around the block of code with a class. Is this possible?

This code

```
<h2><span class="green-text">HEADER</span></h2>
<ul>
    <li>List Item 1</li>
    <li>List Item 2</li>
    <li>List Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Becomes this

```
<div class="callout-wrapper">
<h2>HEADER</h2>
</div>
<ul>
    <li>
<div class="callout-wrapper">List Item 1</div></li>
    <li>
<div class="callout-wrapper">List Item 2</div></li>
    <li>
<div class="callout-wrapper">List Item 3</div></li>
</ul>
```

I like it to do this

```
<div class="callout-wrapper">
<h2>HEADER</h2>
<ul>
    <li>List Item 1</li>
    <li>List Item 2</li>
    <li>List Item 3/li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't a great solution and I'm still looking for one myself, but I thought this might be useful if anyone comes across this like I have just done.

If I select the heading and list and wrap that in my custom style I have the same issue as above.

If I wrap the heading in the custom style, and then create the list then the list itself is wrapped within the div as desired.

Not a perfect solution but will hopefully give some insight.